# How to overlay a bitmap on map view in android?

Tags: android, android-mapview

I want to overlay a bitmap image on map view. I have downloaded a image from url to a Bitmap which contains the image. How to overlay this bitmap on map view in android?

Comment: Better way is to convert Bitmap to Drawable and draw the map overlay Drawable drawOverlay = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an ItemizedOverlay and override the draw() method.

In the draw method you can call,

`canvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap,x,y, paint)`;